# Did I set up my virtualenv incorrectly?

Tags: python, virtualenv, package

My file system looks like this:

home/virtualenv/flaskenv

home/python/flask/[all my flask projects]

I initially set up my virtualenv in the virtualenv/flaskenv folder.
I was under the impression that when I want to use a virtualenv I would need to navigate to that folder and activate it (source flaskenv/bin/activate.fish), and then navigate to my flask projects folder in order to properly run them. However, I am able to run them just fine without activating my virtualenv at all.

I feel like i did something wrong here. I remember when I first started with virtualenv I was confused and ran "pip install flask" (and a couple other packages) in a few different folders, but I don't remember which ones.

How can I figure out if I installed packages in places I shouldn't have? How do I clean them up? note: when I run 'pip freeze' i get a few dozen results, and it's identical for my virtualenv folder, my python folder, and all the individual project folders.

I know very little about the inner workings at this point and I have no clue if this is how it's supposed to work, but I have that nagging feeling that I'm doing it all wrong.

Comment: Mostly likely, all your packages have been installed to `~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`. Either recreate your `flaskenv` dir using `--no-site-packages` flag or you can uninstall them using `pip uninstall package-name` and then activate your flaskenv and then install again.

Comment: @AkashKothawale I considered doing that but there are so so many packages installed that I didn't do myself, so I don't feel like I should uninstall all of them. I did just uninstall a couple that I remember doing myself.  There are about 20 packages called "pyobjc-framework-xxxxx" and those look like system files perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you installed `flask` both system-wide *and* inside each of the virtaulenvs. Then you will be able to run your programs with or without the virtualenv activated. This is not necessarily a problem.

Unless you are dealing with conflicting packages and/or conflicting versions there is no urgent *need* for a virtualenv. They are nice to use, and they facilitate the sharing of source code since you can easily keep track the exact of the dependencies each project has. But installing packages system-wide works as well.

**Akash Kothawale** recommends the use of `--no-site-packages`, but this is the default behavior in newer virtualenv versions. A new virtualenv is supposed to have no packages. To know that you are setting up things correctly, create a new env, acitivate it and run

```
pip freeze
```

before installing anything. This should return an empty list (no output), and your Flask programs won't run. Then install Flask to see that it works again.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. Follow up question: any idea why a package wouldn't show up in pip freeze? The package is definitely installed in one of my virtualenvs but it doesn't appear when i run the command.

Comment: Did you activate the virtualenv? Did you run `pip freeze` without sudo? This important. What is the result of `which pip` inside the virtualenv. What is the full path of the virtualenv? Run `pwd` inside the env.

Comment: So I think it was actually my mistake. I had a virtualenv within a virtualenv, both the same name. When I deleted the inner one, suddenly pip freeze showed the correct packages.